# How to get the actual URL of a browser copied image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, url, paste

Ok, so when we do a "***Copy Image***" on a image (not image location) in Firefox for example, the data is copied to the clipboard.  If we paste into an editable `<div>` and output the HTML of that `<div>`, we can see that it is the actual URL of the image and not the base64 URL or some object URL.  If we paste that into Paint for example, we get the actual image.  Is the URL embedded somewhere inside the clipboard data?  If so, how would we retrieve it on paste?

Here is the code to call for the paste event:

```
let cd = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData);

for (item of cd.items) {
    if (item.type.indexOf("image") >= 0) {
            ..... get the URL value ....

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does cd give you?

Comment: cd is just to ensure some cross browser support for and set the clipboardData object that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the markup data through the `text/html` data type using the [`getData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) method of your DataTransfer object.
Then you just need to [parse that markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and search for the `<img>`'s `src`.

```js
target.onpaste = (e) => {
  const dT = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  const html = dT.getData('text/html') || "";
  const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const img = parsed.querySelector('img');
  if( !img ) { console.warn('no image here'); return; }
  const url = img.src;
  console.log(url);
};
```

```css
#target { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<p><img id="img" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">copy this image by right-click + "Copy Image"</p>
<div contenteditable id="target">Then paste here</div>
```

Comment: hmmm.. I got this as a result:  image.png 2898
�PNG     You actually got the URL shown in the src property?

Comment: @NyaNguyen Sorry I don't know how I could misread that badly your question, I somehow though you wanted to get access to the File... Edited, that's now actually an easier task.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for explaining how to do this in a more straight forward fashion - I don't need to improve my regex for any good purpose. Of more concern to me is that both Chrome and Firefox expose the local file system path of a user who "copy image"s a file they've dragged into an empty browser tab to view. An edge case surely, but any ideas about reporting it as a security issue?

Comment: @traktor53 they only give access to the url in such a case, there is no way to read the content at this address, so I don't think it can be considered a security risk no.

Comment: You can deal with the checkmark as you wish. Just note that as they said, their answrer is not bullet proof (at all). For instance pasting `src="hello world"` will make it think there is something.

Comment: @Kaiido  Perhaps it's thoughtlesness - instead of providing image data without details of a `file://..` url, let's provide the file url without image data. Go figure!

Comment: @traktor They do give the image data (see the first rev. of this answer to get it), but you can't read it from the url.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to provide a url in Firefox:

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener("paste", e=> {
    let cd = e.clipboardData;
    if( cd.items.length == 2) {
       cd.items[0].getAsString( parseFragment) 
    }

    function parseFragment( html) {
        let url = "";
        html.replace( /src\s*=\s*"(.*)"/, (match, p0) => (url = p0) )
        console.log( url);
    }
});
```

```html
<div contentEditable style="border:thick dotted red; height: 100px; width: 200px">
</div>
```

**However**

The code was arrived at by trial and error and head scratching:

- the paste event generates an items object that is a DataTransferList object which is a list of [DataTransferItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem) objects.
- DataTransferItem objects have a `getAsString` method which takes a call back
- A callback requested on the first of two DataTransferItem objects for an image paste operation in Firefox received an html fragment string.
- The regex to get the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag in the string is *rudimentary* - it just looks for a double quoted string.

So I'd say it's at least possible but without claiming the code above is robust.

Determining if Firefox's way of handling image data posts is covered in standards or works in other browsers requires more research. I personally found  no standardized way of finding information about posted image data when looking into it.